# Using calc(100% - x) destroys flex layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using this code to make sure to leave enough space for other elements, but it jums on new line of the flex row.

```
Nav{
    width:200px;
    padding: 1em;
}

Main{
    max-width: calc(100% - 200px - 2em);
}
```

Expected behavior:

```
--------------------------
|         Header         |
--------------------------
|  |                     |
|N |                     |
|a |       Main          |
|v |                     |
|  |                     |
--------------------------
|          Foot          |
--------------------------
```

Actual behavior:

```
--------------------------
|         Header         |
--------------------------
|  |
|N |
|a |
|v |
|  |
-----------------------
|                     |
|                     |
|       Main          |
|                     |
|                     |
--------------------------
|          Foot          |
--------------------------
```

Body have display flex, header, nav, main, foot have flex: 1 auto;
And I found that if I use calc() without percentage.

Comment: There needs to be enough code here to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this adding `float:left` to the nav panel and the main panel.

Here is a JSFiddle that illustrates how this is done: http://jsfiddle.net/WChBm/3/

Ok, you want an answer that uses display:flex. Here is a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p7zEE/

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

#header, #footer {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #4ed;
}

#wrapper {
    height:  calc(100% - 60px);
    display: flex;
}

#nav {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #999;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#main {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #6f5;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Well doesn't work in my case... PS.: The Main have display flex too

Comment: @Akxe - added a solution using flex.